# Suppress control-click context menu, gwt 1.6

Tags: gwt

My gwt 1.6 application intercepts mouse clicks on hyperlinks, so when a user shift-clicks on links to "authors"  they get an Edit... dialog box instead of navigating to the author's page.  That's working nicely.

I'd now like to allow the user to control-click to select more than one author, but I can't figure out how to suppress the browser's default popup menu.  This code handles shift-clicks correctly, but fails in the hosted browser when I control-click and half-fails in Firefox (handleCtrlClick() gets called, but I still get the browser menu):

```
  public void onModuleLoad() {
    Event.addNativePreviewHandler(this);
  }

  //
  // Preview events-- look for shift-clicks on paper/author links, and pops up
  // edit dialog boxes.
  // And looks for control-click to do multiple selection.
  //
  public void onPreviewNativeEvent(Event.NativePreviewEvent pe) {
    NativeEvent e = pe.getNativeEvent();
    switch (Event.getTypeInt(e.getType())) {
    case Event.ONCLICK:
      if (e.getShiftKey()) { handleShiftClick(e); }
      if (e.getCtrlKey()) { handleCtrlClick(e); }
      break;
    case Event.ONCONTEXTMENU:
      if (e.getCtrlKey()) {  // THIS IS NOT WORKING...
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
      }
      break;
    }
  }
```

A breakpoint set inside the ONCONTEXTMENU case is never called.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC ctrl + click is the correct way to select multiple items not ctrl + right click unless you're using a one button mouse (iMac), in that case I can't help you.

Could you provide more details?

**Edit:**

Why not override the contextmenu (e.g. disable it) then create your own context menu widget (perhaps based on vertical MenuBar + MenuItems) and display it only on Ctrl + RightClick?

In other words you'd create a MouseHandler somewhat like this (pseudo code):

```
public void onMouseDown(MouseDownEvent event) {
    Widget sender = (Widget) event.getSource();

    int button = event.getNativeButton();


    if (button == NativeEvent.BUTTON_LEFT) {
        if(event.is_ctrl_also)
        {
             // Add to selection
             selection = selection + sender;
        }
        else
        {
             // Lose selection and start a new one
             selection = sender;
        }
    }
    else if(button == NativeEvent.BUTTON_RIGHT) {
        if(event.is_ctrl_also)
        {
            // show context menu
            this.contextmenu.show();
        }
        else
        {
            // do something else
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

I've not encountered the bug with Ctrl-Leftclick firing a ContextMenu event, but I'm sure you could also make a workaround for Firefox only using permutations.

Comment: The behavior I want:
 control-left-click : multiple select
 right-click : popup the browser's menu.

Problem is that Firefox (at least) treats control-left-click as the SAME as right-click (it fires the oncontextmenu event).

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting closer:

```
  public void onModuleLoad() {
    Event.addNativePreviewHandler(this); // Catch shift- or control- clicks on links
    addContextMenuEventListener(RootPanel.getBodyElement());
  }
```

protected native void addContextMenuEventListener(Element elem) /*-{
    elem.oncontextmenu = function(e) {
      return false; // TODO: only return false if control key down...
    };
  }-*/;
That disables the right-click menu entirely; I'd really like to disable it ONLY if the control key is pressed...